# trouble using defaultDate attribute of datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to write a form that includes multiple datepickers, and I want to define the default date for each of them separately.

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

In line with what this page says (and some of the answers elsewhere on here) the way to do that is with the defaultDate attribute. However, I can only get it to work if it's inside a class, not an ID.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>part of a form page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
                altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                altField: "#altField",
                //defaultDate: 35  //works if uncommented
            });
            $( "#fileDate" ).datepicker({
                defaultDate: 35
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <br/><label>Today's Date: </label>                  <input type="text" name="fileDate" id="fileDate" class="datepicker" required>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I set the default or starting date differently for individual datepicker elements?

**UPDATE**
112g's suggestion worked as far as the functionality's concerned, but in Firefox, it leaves the input boxes highlighted in a red border, as if the user had already entered something, deleted it, and clicked out.
Stranger still, for some reason, ONE of them now behaves as it should, without the red highlighting. It only started behaving after I entered some text, deleted it, and refreshed the page. I tried the same on the other two, as well as rebooting and updating Firefox, to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you first init datepicker using class selector, than you are trying to modify its options using id selector. You have to do this like this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    altField: "#altField",
    defaultDate: 1

});

$( "#date1" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", 35 );
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/112g/pvnvv7nL/)

Comment: That works, thank you! It has the input box outlined in red though, even from page load, as if the user clicked in it and right back out...not fond of that, and would really like to get rid of it.

Comment: Anybody have any idea regarding the red highlighting? It is a required field, granted, but it shouldn't highlight red like that on page load.

Comment: just add `novalidate` attribute to your form tag. `<form .. novalidate>`

Comment: No can do. I tried, and found that there WAS no form tag...*facepalm...Well, that fixed it, in any case, thank you very much!